# DateListPlot does not accept PlotRange or GridLine specifications using DateObject

Tags: date-and-time

This doesn't work...

```
DateListPlot[{{DateObject[{2014, 1, 1}], 1}, 
{DateObject[{2014, 1, 2}], 2}, 
{DateObject[{2014, 1, 3}], 3}}, 
 Joined -> True, GridLines -> {{DateObject[{2014, 1, 2}]}, None}]
```

Neither does this...

```
DateListPlot[{{DateObject[{2014,1,1}],1},
{DateObject[{2014,1,2}],2},
{DateObject[{2014,1,3}],3}}, 
Joined->True, PlotRange->{{DateObject[{2014,1,1}],DateObject[{2014,1,3}]},All}]
```

Converting the values in GridLines and PlotRange to DateLists works.

It seems a bit of an over-sight not to support DateObject here.

The question is should this work?

Comment: Is there a question to be answered here?  Perhaps you could ask a Q and post your answer.  (Others might come up with different answers, too.)

Comment: Removing DateObject[] completeley works too

Comment: @hieron  - Agreed but since DateObject is a new feature and is supported as part of the data series I'm wondering if its non-support in terms of values for GridLines and PlotRange is a bug or I am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Some possibilities to plot `GridLines` with `DateListPlot`:

```
DateListPlot[{
  {{2014, 1, 1}, 1},
  {{2014, 1, 2}, 2},
  {{2014, 1, 3}, 3}},
 PlotTheme -> "Detailed"]
```

[image]

```
DateListPlot[{
  {{2014, 1, 1}, 1},
  {{2014, 1, 2}, 2},
  {{2014, 1, 3}, 3},
  {{2014, 1, 4}, 1}},
 GridLines -> {{{{2014, 1, 2}, Red}, {"Jan 3, 2014", Green}}, Automatic}]
```

[image]

```
DateListPlot[{
  {{2014, 1, 1}, 1},
  {{2014, 1, 2}, 2},
  {{2014, 1, 3}, 3},
  {{2014, 1, 4}, 1}},
 GridLines -> {DateRange["Jan 2, 2014", "Jan 3, 2014"], None}]
```

[image]

**PlotRange**

```
DateListPlot[Sqrt[Range[10]], {2007, 4, 10},
 PlotRange -> {{{2007, 4, 11}, {2007, 4, 17}}, Automatic},
 FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {{"April 11, 2007", "April 17, 2007"}, Automatic}}]
```

[image]

Comment: I agree these work and I can work around the issue but my question is more "is this a bug?".  Thank you for the time and effort and attention.  PlotTheme is new to me so I have learnt something too :).

Comment: @Ymareth It's not a bug - The only thing you have to do is to remove `DateObject`: `GridLines -> {{{2014, 1, 2}}, None}`

Comment: I looks like a bug.  Would you, as a hypothetical Mathematica developer, extend DateListPlot to accept DateObject as x-coordinate values and deliberately avoid their use as values for GridLines and PlotRange?  A bug of omission and one easily worked around but it still looks like a bug to me.

Comment: @Ymareth I was myself surprised that `GridLines` doesn't accept `DateObject`s. "Bug of omission" is a nice definition :)